# Dynamic UITableCellView height

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I followed this tutorial to enable dynamic cell height: http://www.appcoda.com/self-sizing-cells/

So I added

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

in `viewDidLoad`, set labels to 0 Lines and font set to System. The result is that the size of the cell is now dynamic and content is shown correctly but NOT when the table is first displayed. Well some cells are shown correctly but others have a height of 44. When I scroll the table the height seem to be corrected. In the tutorial they describe it like this:

> When the table view is first displayed, you may find some of the cells
>   are not sized properly. But when you scroll the table view, the new
>   cells are displayed with correct row height. To workaround this issue,
>   you can force a reload after the view appears

I tried with

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 64
    self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

but it isn't working. Any ideas how to fix this? I am on xcode 6.1 and iOS8.1 and I am using swift.

I created a simple test project on github: https://github.com/ArtworkAD/DynamicCellTest

Comment: Show you're viewDidLoad() function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I downloaded the project you created on GitHub and made a few changes and got it working.

The code in the ViewController looks like this...

```
import UIKit

class MyTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var entries:Array<String> = [String]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var i = 0
        while i < 20 {
            entries.append("\(i) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor")
            i++;
        }

        self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.entries.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        //ask for a reusable cell from the tableview, the tableview will create a new one if it doesn't have any
        let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("basic_cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

        var label = cell.viewWithTag(13)

        if let unwrappedLabel = label as? UILabel {
            unwrappedLabel.text = self.entries[indexPath.row]
        }

        return cell
    }
}
```

And the Storyboard looks like this...

[image]

Notice the AutoLayout constraints going from top to bottom of the cell and I set the number of lines to 0.

Then when running the app...

[image]

Comment: Hm this is not working for me, I created a simple test project on github. Please check it out https://github.com/ArtworkAD/DynamicCellTest

Comment: @artworkadシ Ah, I see. Have a read of the blog that I linked. It's using a static tableView but the theory is still the same. As far as I have found out you need to be using a custom cell with AutoLayout constraints laying out the contents. Try with a custom cell type and UILabel using AutoLayout.

Comment: I have another question that is very related to this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26757305/dynamic-uitablecellview-height-with-cell-indicator

Answer (score -2):

I think is ok to reload the table in `willDisplayCellMethod` inside a `dispatch_once` block. It is an objective C syntax. You can work out in swift.

```
 -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{

        [self.tableView reloadData];
    });
}
```

Comment: I think this is wrong. This cause the table to display only one cell.

Comment: I just checked it. It works fine for me. I think you should consider your down vote.