# Dynamic UITableCellView height with cell indicator

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

This question is related to another question of mine which was solved: **[Dynamic UITableCellView height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26752645/dynamic-uitablecellview-height)**

I wanted to achieve a dynamic cell height, which is working using this code:

```
import UIKit

class MyTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var entries:Array<String> = [String]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var i = 0
        while i < 20 {
            entries.append("\(i) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor")
            i++;
        }

        self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.entries.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        //ask for a reusable cell from the tableview, the tableview will create a new one if it doesn't have any
        let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("basic_cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

        var label = cell.viewWithTag(13)

        if let unwrappedLabel = label as? UILabel {
            unwrappedLabel.text = self.entries[indexPath.row]
        }

        return cell
    }
}
```

However when I add the disclosure indicator to each cell

```
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.DisclosureIndicator
```

I get this result:

[image]

left with indicator and right without.

You can checkout the github repo of this test project: https://github.com/ArtworkAD/DynamicCellTest

Any ideas whats wrong? I am using swift with xcode 6.1 and iOS8.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that in my original code I had:

```
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 64
```

And this seems to break everything. After I removed this everything works like expected.

Comment: If I rotate a round and I can see text is clipped.

Comment: @gabbler do you have another solution?

Comment: Yes, a hack solution, not very perfect.

Comment: @gabbler share it please!

Comment: Override viewWillTransitionToSize and set tableView.estimatedRowHeight to 36.5